# Entity Framework Code First: Using a database that doesn't need to be separately installed?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite, ef-code-first

I understand that SQL Server Express will work with Code First and is free, but my client doesn't like an additional install step. Is there any other database that I can use that won't need to be installed separately? This is just a single user application so I don't really need a powerful database... just need storage and a way to enforce data integrity.

I did a little research on my own and came up with:

- SQLLite
- SQL Server Compact Edition 4
- MS Access

However, and please correct me if I'm wrong, none of these work with Entity Framework... Any ideas?

EDIT: To put it short: I need an embedded database that supports EF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Sql Server CE and SqlLite are supported by EF. MS Access is not supported. List of supported third party provides is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx). I recommend using Sql CE.

Edit:

I think you only need to install tools fro Sql Server CE 4.0 and then you will be able to define database  in connection string:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Context" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
         connectionString="Data Source=TestDb.sdf"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The name of the connection string should be the name of your derived context.

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to figure out how to use SQL Ce but haven't gone anywhere. Do you have an example of how the connection string would look like? and how do I create the actual file?

Answer (score 2):

try this tutorial. I found it easy to follow.

EF code first with sql compact

It's for asp.net mvc, but it's in C# and should be simple enough to pick out the relevant bits

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx